# Copilot installed but not loaded

Tags: lazy-evaluation, neovim, github-copilot

I use LazyVim, a nice preconfigured setup for NeoVim. I have fixed most of the issues but I can't get copilot working like it used to.

It doesn't show in installed section, but there are filles of copilot.vim in configs folder.

How do i get it to load?

I feel like I'm missing a simple step and am hoping someone here can point me in the right direction...

I've done the usual, fresh install, etc....it just looks like it's not loaded.

I tried :Lazy load copilot.vim but it says a plugin is required.

:Copilot setup gives Copilot is not an editor command, so yeah it isn't loaded....help!